JEL classification quarto-journals
I want to add Journal of Economic Literature (JEL) classification to a quarto-journals/elsevier file.

I see that there's JEL variable defined in _extensions/elsevier/elsarticle.cls, but I don't know how to use it in YAML and it's not mentioned in documentation, so I don't know if it's fully implemented.
There's also a Github issue from sep/2023 asking about it, but the repo seems inactive.
Should I implement it or am I missing something?

Support to JEL codes wasn't fully implemented, missing a few lines in before-body.tex:
\begin{keyword}
    $for(keywords/allbutlast)$$keywords$ \sep $endfor$
    $for(keywords/last)$$keywords$$endfor$
    % added lines here -------------------------------
    $if(JEL)$
        \JEL{
            $for(JEL/allbutlast)$$JEL$ \sep $endfor$
            $for(JEL/last)$$JEL$$endfor$
        }
    $endif$
    % end edit ---------------------------------------
\end{keyword}

PR opened upstream, waiting for merge.
